# Displaying Facebook popups with .net Facebook SDK

Tags: asp.net, facebook

Anyone know how to do this? I would like to programatically (sp?) open a box asking my users to type in what to publish, but I want it to look like Facebook's own boxes.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the .NET sdk will do this for you. You will have to write or steal some JavaScript from elsewhere to handle the popups, and then control them and then control publishing from your back end.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Will have to use a modalpopup (ajax) and find someone's css to mimic the boxes :p

Comment: This is correct. The Facebook C# SDK has nothing to do with client side javascript.

Comment: There are some pre-made javascript sources that may help you get started. This is one example, Google can help you find more: http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-lightbox

Comment: I made a custom control for this, if anyone's interested. Will activate from client side and/or server side...

Comment: Sure, share it on Github or something if you want. I'll check it out.